# Android Get External UI Component Handles

Tags: android, user-interface, junit

Is there a method/work around for a process to receive external UI component handles in the Android platform?

The reason why I am doing this is to benchmark applications, so I would like to read and log application states (UI component numbers, texts, positions, layout so forth) via a service. This will only be for testing purposes, so requiring root privileges or something like that is okay.

In the windows world, I would use win32 APIs or some other API to access UI components. Of course, to my understanding, Android is designed not to allow this, in this case a work around, hack, tweak (again this is only for testing purposes) or direction of the proper method complying to the Android philosophy to implement this functionally will be welcomed.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is one UI component called droid Draw.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. I will investigate Droid Draw.